# Default logged in user to SQL Server column

Tags: sql-server, default

How can I create a column with a default value of the user that created the row at the time in the table?

I tried `system_user`, but that shows who is logged in when selecting from the table.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE DemoTable
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
    SomeValue VARCHAR(50), 
    CreatedBy VARCHAR(50) 
        CONSTRAINT DF_DemoTable_CreatedBy DEFAULT(SUSER_NAME())
)
```

You basically create a **default constraint** on one of your columns, and you use the `SUSER_NAME()` function to populate it with the currently logged in user.

When you then insert values into that table:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.DemoTable(SomeValue) VALUES('Some Value')
```

and you **don't** specify an explicit value for `CreatedBy`, that column is filled with the value from the `SUSER_NAME()` function, which you can check by selecting from the  table:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.DemoTable
```

[Read more about `SUSER_NAME()` and a few related functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187934.aspx) (like `SUSER_ID()`) on TechNet.

Comment: Thx, That did it!  The problem was, I used the computed value functionality.... Question, is there a way of restriction a user from adding the into "CreatedBy" manually....